# Merging VS2010 WebForms app into existing VS2012 MVC4 app in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, visual-studio-2013

I want to merge two Web App projects created in VS2010 and 2012 respectively into one Web app project in VS2013. The VS2010 app is a WebForms app and the VS2012 app is an MVC4 app.

This is what I have done so far: I opened the MVC4 app in VS2013 and ran as normal. I was expected VS2013 to launch a upgrade wizard and convert the app to VS2013 version by including some extra references, features etc.

1. Why wizard did not launch?
2. Can I just add the WebForm app to this new VS2013 project by creating a folder and add all the WebForms files into it and compile the entire project. Or, there are some prerequisite steps I need to take.

Comment: Let me speculate that VS2012 and 13 are so close that there is no need to convert from one to another - they are the same in regards to projects. And yes, I believe you can just add your Web forms. This is all about templates. And you can manually add templates Id in proj file. For example, in WebApp Proj you can add template Id for MVC and you will be able to use menu "Add-Controller...". Otherwise you will still be able to but manually. You will not have Action stubs in that case

Comment: You probably want to upgrade the Project to MVC5, that enables all these nice features: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/12/upgrade-your-existing-aspnet-mvc4.html

Comment: Thanks to T.S. It worked but VS2013 would hang when I run the project in the debug mode. So, I moved the project to VS2012 where it is working fine.